# adding to :effects in :before function in re-frame interceptors

Tags: interceptor, clojurescript, effects, re-frame

I have this **working** piece of code:

```clj
(rf/reg-fx :mr-effect (fn [] (js/console.log "I AM MR EFFECT.")))

(def mr-interceptor
  (rf/->interceptor
   :id    :mr-interceptor
   :after (fn [context] (assoc-in context [:effects :mr-effect] "some_arg"))))
```

So, when I attach `mr-interceptor` to an event handler, then all is good and I can see "I AM MR EFFECT." printed out.

But, as soon as I change `:after` to `:before`, like this:

```clj
(def mr-interceptor
  (rf/->interceptor
   :id    :mr-interceptor
   :before (fn [context] (assoc-in context [:effects :mr-effect] "some_arg"))))
```

Then the desired side effect does not happen. So, my reasoning is that `:before` cannot register such side effects to be triggered. But... am I right? Can `:before` change `:effects` in any way that's meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conclusion is correct. Event handlers are called in the last interceptor in the chain (it's added automatically by re-frame) and that interceptor uses simple `(assoc ctx :effects ...)`. So it will overwrite whatever you put in `:effects` during any previous step.